# after git add and git commit, so many insertions and deletions even though i only changed 4 lines

Tags: git

I'm at my wits end. I tried to fix this by changing the settings/preferences on my code editor (vscode), changing to another code editor (atom, sublime), configured git core.autocrlf to both true and false but still to no avail. I found out that when I open(check out) the branch for the first time, the said problem arises but after editing my code again, git add and git commit again it's back to normal.

Comment: That's because your editor made changes to every line. After adding and committing, your editor stopped making changes to every line the *next* time.

Comment: is that the default behavior of code editors? I tried it also on atom and sublime, it's the same even though I've added only 4 lines of code

Comment: Depends. Some editors expand tabs to spaces, for instance, so that if the original code has tabs, and you have turned on the "no tabs ever" option, you get spaces. Some editors un-expand spaces to tabs, for instance, so that if the original code has spaces... https://www.google.com/search?q=tabs+vs+spaces

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the changes (eol or spaces).
Make sure to have `git config --global core.autocrlf false`, then launch your editor.

Since I have never experienced that issue with VSCode, try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), with its [Git Lens plugin](https://gitlens.amod.io/) installed: you should not have any issue on a new local clone
 of your repository.